# Tasks not finishing before process end

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, garbage-collection, async-await

In my code in the main thread I call a 3rd party API. For each result from the API I call 2 async tasks. Sometimes all works perfectly, sometimes not all async tasks run. I suppose that when the main thread finishes, the garbage collector kills all my other tasks that run in the background. Is there any way to tell garbage collector not to kill the background services when the main thread finishes?

The code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var demo = new AsyncAwaitTest();
    demo.DoStuff1(guid);
    demo.DoStuff2(guid);
}

public class AsyncAwaitTest
{
     public async Task DoStuff1(string guid)
     {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DoSomething1(guid);
        });   
     }

     public async Task DoStuff2(string guid)
     {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DoSomething2(guid);
        });   
     }

     private static async Task<int> DoSomething1(string guid)
     {
        // insert in db or something else
        return 1;
     }

     private static async Task<int> DoSomething2(string guid)
     {
        // insert in db or something else
       return 1;
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Garbage collector does not kill tasks -> if it does then I bet the tasks are coded "wrong"

Comment: `i suppose that when main Thread finish, garbage collector kills all my other tasks that run in background.` this is not normal behavior.

Comment: Incomplete code. You only create some Tasks but you don't Start or await anything. This really needs a [mcve].

Comment: Please make your code more readable, it's  to hard to read this code for idents and brackets

Comment: What do you mean by `main` thread? is it your main-process thread?

Comment: If you want to continue execution of a thread when your program exits you should use a foreground thread.

Comment: How do you indicate your threads stop halfway in their execution? Could their own task simply end due to another problem (db connection failed, etc)?

Comment: in each async task i insert just a descr in a db timeseries to see which tasks runs and which not, so some tasks are missing from db

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wait for all your tasks to finish, you have to collect them and wait for them. Because when your process ends, that normally is the end of everything.

```
var tasks = List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var demo = new AsyncAwaitTest();
    tasks.Add(demo.DoStuff1(guid));
    tasks.Add(demo.DoStuff2(guid));
}

// before your process ends, you need to make sure all tasks ave finished.
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

You also have **2** levels of carelessness (meaning you start a task and don't care whether it's done). You need to remove the second one, too:

```
public async Task DoStuff1(string guid)
{
   await DoSomething1(guid);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, does this solution guarantee that the tasks will run even the main thread finish earlier?

Comment: @TeO Yes and no. It guarantees that the main thread will **wait** until all others have finished. Because there is no way to keep your tasks if the process ends.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, regarding the second part that you say i have to remove, can you be more specific please?

Comment: @TeO For you to be able to **wait** for tasks, you must never just abandon them. For example calling a method returning a task... and then just ignoring the result. All tasks must be waited on.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so in that way , is there any reason to use async task? is it the same if i call all synchronous? i used async in order the main thread to finish quickly, in that way the main thread will finish as soon as all async tasks will finish, right?

Comment: Your main thread (process) waiting for all other parts to finish, does not mean it needs to wait for all of them **one after the other**. It still does it all in parallel.