# Is there a way to globally WaitAll() for all tasks created by a process?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I have a process which does logging by calling an external service. Because of the overhead involved (small, but builds up for many logging messages), my process logs asynchronously, in a "fire and forget" kind of way. I don't want to wait for each log message to go through before continuing, and I don't want to fail my process for a problem with the logger.

In order to accomplish this, I have wrapped the main log call in a Task - each call to logging fires off a Task, which just goes off and does it's thing. Most of the time, my process loops through the things it needs to check, handles them, and then exits just fine, logging all the way. However, on those occasions when it finds only a single item to handle, the process completes so quickly that the process exits, thus killing all of its threads, before the logging actually happens, and I get almost nothing in the logs.

I have confirmed that this is what is happening by checking that the items are handled as expected even when they are not logged (they are), and by putting a short (100 millisecond) delay into the logging method (outside of the Task), so that the logging DOES actually block. In this case, everything logs as expected.

(Based on this, I actually believe that even when the process works as expected, we may be missing a couple of log entries from the end of each run, since it is exiting before the last entries can go through, but I haven't been able to tell for certain.)

I could just put a delay at the very end of the process, so that no matter what, it hangs at at least a second or two to give these "fire and forget" Tasks time to complete, but that feels clunky.

Another option I'm considering is creating a global list of logging Tasks that will collect the Tasks as they are created, so that I can do a Task.WaitAll() on them. This feels like a bit of overhead I shouldn't have to deal with, but it may be the best solution.

What I'm looking for is some way to, at the end of my process, do a WaitAll() type of call that doesn't require me to know what Tasks I'm waiting for - just wait for any and all Tasks still hanging out there (except for the main Thread of the process, of course).

Does such a thing exist, or do I need to just keep track of all of my Tasks globally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453915/tasks-not-finishing-before-process-end this does require you to have a reference to your task. You may need to rethink your problem

Comment: Note that "Task" is not synonymous with "Thread". While a Task may be assigned to a thread, it can also be run synchronously.

Comment: You need to keep track of them yourself. After all, you wouldn't want to accidentally wait on a Task created by unrelated code that was truly fire-and-forget. e.g. `var discardedTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(999));` Or worse, grab somebody else's task and reconfigure it!

Comment: @RaymondChen Well, technically I would want to wait on Tasks created by random code as well - if I don't they will be killed when the process ends. After all, this only covers Tasks created within this process. "Somebody else's Task" is still a Task created within this process...

Comment: Hunting down tasks created by other components violates encapsulation. In the above case, your app will pause at shutdown for 999 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a task aggregator, a task that completes when all observed tasks are completed. It would be a functionally equivalent version of `Task.WhenAll`, but much more lightweight since only the number of incomplete tasks would be stored, not the tasks themselves. Here is an implementation of this idea:

```
public class TaskAggregator
{
    private int _activeCount = 0;
    private int _isAddingCompleted = 0;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public Task Task { get => _tcs.Task; }

    public int ActiveCount
    {
        get => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _activeCount, 0, 0);
    }

    public bool IsAddingCompleted
    {
        get => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isAddingCompleted, 0, 0) != 0;
    }

    public void Add(Task task)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _activeCount);
        task.ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            int localActiveCount = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _activeCount);
            if (localActiveCount == 0 && this.IsAddingCompleted)
                _tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isAddingCompleted, 1);
        if (this.ActiveCount == 0) _tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static TaskAggregator LogTasksAggregator = new TaskAggregator();

public static void Log(string str)
{
    var logTask = Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(str);
    LogTasksAggregator.Add(logTask);
}

// End of program
LogTasksAggregator.CompleteAdding();
bool completedInTime = LogTasksAggregator.Task.Wait(5000);
if (!completedInTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LogTasksAggregator timed out");
}
```

Comment: So, no option exists like I was looking for - I will need to keep track of Tasks and wait on them myself. That said, I like this approach - more lightweight than maintaining a full list of Tasks and waiting on all of them.

Comment: It seems that the .NET Framework is well optimized and can handle millions of tasks like a champ. For example waiting for 50,000,000 completed tasks takes slightly more than a second in my machine, and each task consumes no more than 50 bytes of memory. But still it seems wasteful to keep in memory every completed task of a program!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using `internal Task[] System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasksForDebugger()` as documented in [TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasks Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks) but it doesn't seem to return tasks that are currently running:

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sleeping");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
});

// Retrieve method info for internal Task[] GetScheduledTasksForDebugger()
var typeInfo = typeof(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler);
var bindingAttr = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
var methodInfo = typeInfo.GetMethod("GetScheduledTasksForDebugger", bindingAttr);

Task[] tasks = (Task[])methodInfo.Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.Current, null);
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I think you're going to have to manage a `List<Task>` and WaitAll on that.

Comment: The documentation says that it returns tasks that are "currently queued to the scheduler waiting to be executed." A task that is still pending isn't "waiting to be executed." "Waiting to be executed" means that the task is ready to run and is waiting its turn.